# loop adding variables to database with laravel php

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

For some reason my script returns noimage.jpg and no image is stored. Not too sure why ? It constructs the correct filename but appears not to match the two terms for some reason? e.g. it constructs 'image1' but when 'image1' field is filled out doesnt see them matching?

**User Uploads Photos:**

```
   <div class="section4 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::file('image1.jpg')}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::file('image2')}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::file('image3')}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::file('image4')}}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
for($i=1; $i<=16; $i++){
        $filenamestr = (string)('image'.$i);
        if($request->hasFile($filenamestr)){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image'.$i)->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('image'.$i)->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('image'.$i)->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're always submitting 16 images?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy not always. Maximum of 16 but number is user defined. So if they upload 2 only want two names to go to database and so on

Comment: No, it is 16. That loop *will* run 16 times based on *your* code.

Comment: @Script47 I was meaning to write a script for upto 16

Answer (score 0):

The final value of `$fileNameToStore` is being set to the 16th iteration of the loop which is `noimage.jpg`. However it does look like your images should still be stored if they are present.

You can solve the first issue by creating an array of filenames to store:

```
for($i=1; $i<=16; $i++){
    $filenamestr = (string)('image'.$i);
    if($request->hasFile($filenamestr)){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image'.$i)->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('image'.$i)->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore[$i]= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('image'.$i)->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore[$i]);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore[$i] = 'noimage.jpg';
    }
}

dd($fileNameToStore);
```

For the second issue, 
remember to check that your form has `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"...` set. Also check the server has write access to your `cover_images` folder.

Also check the name of your first input as it shouldn't have the `.jpg` at the end.

Finally, consider using `$request->file('image'.$i)->isValid()` before storing to check the file is valid.

**Finally**

Consider using an array input rather than numbered fields. I.e. call each field `{{Form::file('image[]')}}` and use Laravel's support of [`dot` notation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input) or a `foreach($request)->file()`

Comment: Thank you so much :) however, I get an error ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Array to string conversion

Comment: Apologies there was a typo in the `storeAs` line, it was missing the array pointer. Fixed now.